# Angular - building component library that can be imported one component at a time

Tags: angular, npm, angular9, angular-library

I'm relatively new to Angular. A project I'm working on includes, as part of its spec, a component library that can be imported wholesale or one component at a time. In other words, sort of like `lodash`, you should be able to do either this:

```
yarn add -D lodash
```

or just this (if you don't want all the bloat, and just want the one function):

```
yarn add -D lodash/get
```

I found [this article](https://medium.com/@tomsu/how-to-build-a-library-for-angular-apps-4f9b38b0ed11), which is a helpful walkthrough (though maybe a bit old) for setting up a component library in Angular. I also looked through the [Angular documentation on building libraries](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries), which covered similar ground. But it looks like both only set up for the importing of the whole library, not the component-by-component import that we would like.

Does anybody know either

1. how to alter this setup to add that functionality, or
2. where I could find resources that would help me figure this out?

Similarly, we're hoping to have this component-library repository define global styles that could be used across a range of apps that import the component library. Does anybody know of resources that show how to export a CSS/SCSS file from an Angular library? (And allow it to be similarly imported as its own thing, without importing the whole library?).

Or does anyone have architectural advice for how to structure this? I want to make sure I start off in the right direction, and don't make a mess of things from the start.

Thanks. I've been looking, but I'm not very familiar with the Angular ecosystem -- and in particular, am unfamiliar with the whole Angular module/dependency setup that seems core to this problem -- and am not sure I know where best to look.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend you to use [**`nx`**](https://nx.dev/angular/getting-started/what-is-nx).

Comment: Thanks! Will take a look